# Zero length intervals in R ivs package?

Tags: r, date, datetime

Is it possible to have zero length date intervals in R ivs package iv?

Let's assume, we have a following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(start = as.Date(c("2021-10-01", "2021-10-02", "2021-10-03")),
                 end = as.Date(c("2021-10-10", "2021-10-02", "2021-10-20")))
```

|  | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-01 | 2021-10-10 |
| 2 | 2021-10-02 | 2021-10-02 |
| 3 | 2021-10-03 | 2021-10-20 |

The row number two has a zero length interval (it's just zero full days; the time between start and end on row two is less than one day, to be exact).

However, when I try to create an iv object:

```
iv_object <- iv(start = df$start, end = df$end)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in `iv()`:
! `start` must be less than `end`.
i `start` is not less than `end` at locations: `2`.
```

If I change "2021-10-02" to "2021-10-03" (or any date after "2021-10-02") in the "end" column, everything works just fine, which is no surprise given the information from the error message.

Is there a way to circumvent this? I was thinking, if I should add time to the date, so that the start would be always like, say, %YYYY-%mm-%dd:01:00:00 and end %YYYY-%mm-%dd:02:00:00 (so the second line would be:

start: 2021-10-02:01:00:00

end:   2021-10-02:02:00:00).

Does this hack have any downsides?

Comment: The `as.Date()` function will essentially remove the time, so that won't work.  You could make it a date-time object with (e.g., `lubridate::ymd_h("2021-10-02 00")`), but then the intervals will include the times, so there will still be no zero intervals.

Comment: Does the time of day actually matter for your computations? If _not_, then the closest pure date equivalent to the ivs interval of `[2021-10-02 01:00:00, 2021-10-02 02:00:00)` would be `[2021-10-02, 2021-10-03)` (since you can't have an empty interval). But I imagine the time of day probably would affect the final result, so if you know the time of day then it is probably best to go ahead and attach it on and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute time intervals between dates using the `lubridate` package.
in the code below `interval(start,end)` compute the interval in an r Interval object (time spans), Intervals can be accurately converted to either period or duration objects using `as.duration()`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(start = as.Date(c("2021-10-01", "2021-10-02", "2021-10-03")),
                 end = as.Date(c("2021-10-10", "2021-10-02", "2021-10-20")))
df=df%>%
  mutate(int=interval(start,end),int_d=int/ddays(1))
df
#>        start        end                            int int_d
#> 1 2021-10-01 2021-10-10 2021-10-01 UTC--2021-10-10 UTC     9
#> 2 2021-10-02 2021-10-02 2021-10-02 UTC--2021-10-02 UTC     0
#> 3 2021-10-03 2021-10-20 2021-10-03 UTC--2021-10-20 UTC    17

as.duration(df$int)
#> [1] "777600s (~1.29 weeks)"  "0s"                     "1468800s (~2.43 weeks)"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>